# Mac Catalyst: AVAudioSession.availableInputs returns no inputs

Tags: swift, avaudiosession, mac-catalyst

I am trying to port audio input to Mac Catalyst. As of now I am using xcode13GM, macOS 10.15 Beta 8 (19A558d), ios13beta8. The following code does not return any input ports.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

var mic : AVAudioSessionPortDescription? = nil
for input in audioSession.availableInputs! {
  if input.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.builtInMic {
    mic = input
  } else {
    print("Not internal mic")
}

// here: 'mic' is nil
```

I have granted the "Hardend Runtime - Audio Input" entitlement and the app asks for microphone permission which is granted.

When accessing audioSession.availableInputs the following error shows up in the console:

> [avas] AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:258:-[AVAudioSession
>   getChannelsFromAU:PortName:PortID:]: ERROR in getting channel layout
>   for auScope 1768845428 element 1

Is this a bug due to beta status of the whole stuff or am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Same here. I guess the `AVAudioSession` isn't fully implemented for `Mac Catalyst` yet. For instance, when I call `try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)` I get the error `Error Domain=AVAudioSessionErrorDomain Code=-4 "Unimplemented"`, which is pretty self explanatory. Well, let's wait for the next Mac Catalina version then

Comment: Problem still persists under 10.15 beta 10 and Xcode 11.1GM. I have filed a bug report, but as usual no feedback from Apple.

Comment: Still the same problem 6 months later. Filed a bug report as well...

Comment: @pms-pms Could you please provide a link to the bug report?

Comment: This is sad. Just when I thought I could make one app and deploy on iOS and MacOS, here we go again...

Comment: @Chris Have you got a chance to get it working with the new version of MacOS and Xcode?

Comment: No, but the speech API works for non-Catalyst apps. After bug report, forum chat and some communication with apple stuff who confirmed the problem I finally gave up ;-( They didn't fix it for months and I doubt they intend to fix it in the future...